# How to modify the QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt

I want to non-display the space between parent `QWidgetItem` and child-Item... How can i do that. `style-Sheet` ?.. thank you!!!

this is a `QTreeWidget`.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#indentation-prop

```
indentation : int
```

This property holds indentation of the items in the tree view.

This property holds the indentation measured in pixels of the items for each level in the tree view. For top-level items, the indentation specifies the horizontal distance from the viewport edge to the items in the first column; for child items, it specifies their indentation from their parent items.

By default, this property has a value of 20.

Access functions:

```
int indentation () const
void    setIndentation ( int i )
```