# How to remove the empty space at the left of a QTreeView

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface, qtreeview

I have a subclassed `QTreeView`. I need to make it looks like simple `QListView` without space (left corner spacing) for child items. What should I do? Qt is **4.7.4**.
Already tried `setRootIsDecorated` and it doesn't help. I have tried `QTreeView::setIndentation`, but it doesn't help too.

[image: QTreeview spacing]

Comment: Try using `QTreeView::setIndentation`

Comment: There is the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499808/how-to-modify-the-qtreewidget).

Comment: If it doesn' help show how you fill your treeview.

Comment: Great answer! I fill my tree views from model too and I don't have any problems with the indentation :/

Comment: Ok. Which method do you want to see?

Comment: Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Just show how you add those three elements in your picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in the methods which somehow changes my `QTreeView`. So, setting indentation after this methods solved the problem. But I still don't understand why setting indentation in the constructor of `QTreeView` was useless.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with QTreeWidgets, they have a "rootIsDecorated" setting that is enabled by default. Disable it, job done.